# How interfaces reduce the complexity of connections between modules and with the external environment?

Tags: java, interface, uml

As I read in CHAPTER 13 DESIGN CONCEPTS AND PRINCIPLES

Book: Software Engineering A PRACTITIONER’S APPROACH
by Roger S. Pressman,FIFTH EDITION:

`6.A design should lead to interfaces that reduce the complexity of 
connections between modules and with the external environment`

How interfaces reduce the complexity of connections
between modules and with the external environment?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that instead of describing all possible connections thanks to specific types, you simply have to describe them with interfaces and then at the implementation step all you need is to be sure that your type implementing the dedicated interface.

Here two examples:
1) Without using interfaces

[image]

2) using interfaces

[image]

Hoping it is clear,

Regards,

EBR

Comment: thanks @Red Beard . What do you mean by `describing all possible connections thanks to specific types` ? Any example explains that would be very appreciated

Comment: The usage of interface, or at least general abstract classes, allows to quickly see how to made connection. I added two screenshot in my previous response in order to represent this point.